# Differential rotations in Chebyshev net

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

A Chebyshev net obeying Sine-Gordon equation is drawn on a surface of constant negative Gauss curvature $K$ so that the asymptotic differential rhombic element *corners* lie on lines of maximum/minimum normal curvature.

Show that principal rotation of surface normals across diagonals ($\phi_1$ = const,  $\phi_2 $ = const.) of rhombus are related as:

$$ d \phi_1^2 + d \phi_2^2 = - K ds^2  \tag{0} $$

which is a hyperbolic metric with rotation  $\phi_1,\phi_2$ as parameters.

EDIT1:

The following fully reinforces original view  of hyperbolic geometry where the parameters $ (\phi_1,  \phi_2 )$ take the place of $(u,v)$ in the Euclidean metric up to an invariant constant $a$ :

$$ ds^2= du^2 + dv^2  \tag{1} $$

Let $ K= -1/a^2$ , primes with respect to hyperbolic geodesic asymptotic arcs

$$ \phi_1^{\prime2} +\phi_2^{\prime2} = \frac{1}{a^2}  \tag{2}$$

Taking components of arc along direction inclined at $\psi$ to fiber along maximum and minimum curvature directions we have by definition of constant $K$:

$$ \frac{d \phi_1}{ds \cos \psi} \cdot \frac{d \phi_2}{ds \sin \psi} =  \frac{ \phi_1 ^{\prime}}{ \cos \psi} \cdot \frac{  \phi_2 ^{\prime}}{ \sin \psi}  =\frac{1}{a^2} \tag{3} $$

Solving (2),(3) we obtain derivatives of rotation w.r.t. arc in each direction as:

$$\phi_1^{\prime} = \frac { \cos \psi} {a}, \;\phi_2^{\prime} = \frac { \sin \psi} {a}    \tag{4} $$

as one solution taken out of two interchangeable solutions. Squaring and adding,

$$  \boxed{ds^2 = a^2( d \phi_1^2 + d \phi_2^2) }  \tag{5} $$

What prompts me to post this is: Recognition of this observed ***identity between Euclidean and Hyperbolic parameters*** to hopefully remove vagueness (in my mind at least) while recognizing these rotations as hyperbolic parameters:

Thus the above is the ***curvilinear hyperbolic geodesic Pythagoras theorem***. Hypotenuse is allowed only along hyperbolic geodesics and components only along maximum/minimum normal curvature lines.

I have no access to good literature references/ sources but had held this view within myself that... this was Beltrami's original conceptualization. Request enlightened members to please make corrections and give comments on my view.

> $$  (u,v) \leftrightarrow a (\phi_1 , \phi_2 ) \tag{6} $$

[image: Hyp_Geods_Pseudosphere/metric]

In this connection I quote from the text book authored by DJ Struik, *Lectures on Classical Differential Geometry*, Second edition pp 153 left bottom:

> The whole geometry of Lobachevski-Bolyai could thus be interpreted on
>   a surface of constant negative curvature , *parallel lines becoming
>   geodesics* (Emphasis mine). Beltrami proved that the
>   consistency of implied consistency of Lobachevski-Bolyai geometry,
>   since an inconsistency in the latter could be interpreted as an
>   inconsistency in the theory of surfaces of constant negative (Gauss)
>   curvature which itself is based on Euclidean postulates.

Above image is made on *Mathematica* based on the  metric correspondence (6). The discussion is for any surface, not necessarily that of revolution as pictured.

EDIT2:

Derivation:

$ \kappa_{1,2}$ principal curvatures. Euler's normal curvature relation:

$$  \kappa_n =\kappa_1 \cos^2 \psi + \kappa_2 \sin ^2 \psi =0 ;\, \kappa_1 \kappa_2  = -1/a^2 \, \rightarrow \kappa_{1,2}= (-\tan\psi/a, \cot\psi/a) \tag{7}$$

Line segment components along curvature extrema directions :

$$ 2 \, d \phi_1 = 2 \, ds\, \cos \psi \, \kappa_1,\, 2\,d\phi_2 = 2 \, ds \, \sin \psi \, \kappa_2,\ \tag{8} $$

Combining (7),(8) to eliminate $\kappa_{1,2}$ we get (5) or (0).

EDIT3:

Constant negative hyperbolic lines $K$ *in the large*  for orthogonal lines *should* accordingly be given by:

$$ \cosh (ds/a) = \cosh d \phi_1\,  \cosh d \phi_2\ $$

and *in the small* by

$$ 1 + (ds/a)^2/2 \approx (1 + d\phi_1^2/2)\,(1 + d\phi_2^2/2) $$

so that we have same:

$$  ds^2 = a^2(d\phi_1^2 + d\phi_2^2 ). \tag{10=5} $$

EDIT 4:

Further on I bring out a simple but an equally important ***isometric identity of rotation product*** $ ( d \phi_1.d \phi_2) $  and second differential of $\psi $ which appears to be implied or hidden.

From (4)

$$ d \phi_1 =\frac {ds \cos \psi}{R_1}= \kappa_1  {ds \cos \psi};\quad d \phi_2 =\frac {ds \sin \psi}{R_2}= \kappa_2  {ds \sin\psi};\quad \tag {11 }$$

$$ d \phi_1 . d \phi_2 =\kappa_1 \kappa_2 \, ds \cos \psi  \,ds \sin \psi  = K ds^2 \sin \psi\, \cos \psi \tag{12} $$

By Sine-Gordon theorem for half the scissor angle $ 2 \psi$

$$ \psi^{''}=  \frac{d^2\psi}{ds^2}=K \sin\psi \cos\psi =\kappa_1 \kappa_2 \sin\psi \cos\psi  \tag {13} $$

From (13) and (12) the scalar differential rotation product is:

$$ \boxed{ d^2\psi  = d \phi_1 . d \phi_2} \tag{14} $$

Comment: Something is wrong with your equation.  The metric on the left, $d\phi_1^2+d\phi_2^2$, is obviously flat, but the metric on the right, $-K ds^2$, has constant negative Gauss curvature $-1$.  Or do you not mean $ds^2$ to be the induced metric?

Comment: These *rotations*  are calculated and culminate in correct equations (4). Does taking as induced metric help?

Comment: @ Robert Bryant At the end is included a short derivation for the apparently " flat metric".I wish  to know if there are more fundamental ways to prove it...however....

Comment: Replacing dimensionless lengths by angles this way is  fundamental to non-Euclidean geometries as it appears to me.. generating lengths via small angular arguments  and then compensatingly  back again with a dimensional invariant , as in: $ a\, \sinh\, s/a  \approx s .$ Shallow first order approximations  result when $ s<< a$ working  out to distances/ arc lengths in Euclidean geometry.

Comment: Please be aware that each edit bumps the question to the front of the active questions list, at the expense of other questions which are vying for attention. Better is to do only a few edits to correct many infelicities within the same edit, rather than many edits to do one or two at a time.

Comment: To all... The requested proposition has been self answered in the derivation  of equations (7,8)  confirming that these rotations in fact are the rotational  parameters that characterize non-Euclidean  *hyperbolic geometry metric* after division by an invariant  $ \sqrt {-K} $ .. a view for which an answer is awaited.

Comment: For asymptotic lines all points are inflection points. Asymptotic curves have constant geodesic  torsion $\frac{1}{a},$ being  straight along this direction, Tangent plane is same as (coincides with)  osculating plane ... as is known.

Comment: And now we have differential arc lengths $ a \, d\phi_1,a \, d\phi_2 $ obeying the Pythagoras theorem with hypotenuse lying  along asymptotic line and sides along  direction of extreme normal curvatures.

Comment: This can happen as the arc is straight. With $ R_n = 1/k_n= \infty $ the metric need not necessarily be  the *only* flat metric. *The asymptotic line of constant negative $K$ can have an admissible non-euclidean claim for generalization of the metric*.

Comment: @ Todd Trimble The "in the large" relevance is necessary, I ought to have mentioned it in the first place.

Comment: As Robert Bryant pointed out, if your surface has metric $ds^2$ (which would coincide with the conventional notation) and $K$ is a negative constant, then the expression $d\phi_1^2 + d\phi_2^2=-K \, ds^2$ ensures that the metric is a constant multiple of a flat metric $ds^2=(-1/K)(d\phi_1^2+d\phi_2^2)$, as Robert Bryant pointed out, since it is a multple of the flat Euclidean metric in the coordinates $\phi_1, \phi_2$. You seem to be ignoring this problem. I don't know what "asymptotic differential rhombic element corners" are; please give a reference to define $\phi_1, \phi_2$.